# SonarQube Report not getting generated

Tags: sonarqube

I am running Sonar on some old Java Application. There are few test case failures in that Application. When i run Sonar it is not generating report and Build is failing because of failure test cases. Is there is a way to generate Report even in case of failed test cases. Looking for help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By failed I assume you mean test case failure, not an error in the sonar upload process.

Check that sonar-scanner completed successfully when you ran it:

```
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
```

If you're using Maven, analyzing a Java project requires a Maven goal `sonar:sonar` in project's root dir.

Specify the SonarQube server connection in your `pom.xml`:

```
<settings>
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>sonar</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
    <sonar.login><ADMIN_TOKEN></sonar.login>
        <sonar.projectName>My Project</sonar.projectName>
        <sonar.projectVersion>master</sonar.projectVersion>
        <sonar.test.exclusions>**/test/**/*.*</sonar.test.exclusions>  
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```